# Devise/Rspec - Tested a user creation with (maybe) missing attributes (got true..)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am testing Devise with Rspec using Micheal Hartl source code (railstutorial)

Whereas the confirmable module is enabled, I don't understand why this test pass:

## spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { :username => "ExampleUser", 
              :email => "user@example.com",
              :password => 'test1234',
            }
    end

  it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
    User.create!(@attr)
  end 
end
```

Basically, I want to be sure of this code does, it tests the creation on the user, not this validation (cause the user has not confirmed yet and the test returns true) ? This is right?

Moreover, I didn't provide attribute for password confirmation, and the user is still created!

Is this mean that in the :validatable module there is not (?):

```
validates :password, :confirmation => true
```

Thanks to get you view on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one problem is the trailing comma at the end of your each block. second, you are not asserting anything in your test to pass or fail the test, though you are probably erroring out at this point, which is why you are saying it didnt pass.

you can try assigning the user object to a variable:

```
  it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
    @user = User.new(@attr) 
    @user.should be_valid #=> new will let you know if its valid or not
    @user.save.should be_true #=> another possible assertion to pass/fail the test
    # debug message to give you back why it failed
    puts @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
  end
```